# Как получить данные из Execute или Enqueue в Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Я новичок в Android и Java разработке, так что не пинайте сильно;)
Суть в чём: нужно проверить валидность токена, который хранится в приложении. Я отправляю токен на сервер и смотрю, какой StatusCode он мне возвращает. Делаю я это через Retrofit2 так:

```
public class ServerRequester {
    private static boolean loginResult;

    public static boolean IsValidToken(Context context) {
        boolean loginResult = false;
        DbContext db = new DbContext(context);
        String token = db.GetToken();
        Call<TokenCheck> call = Requests.CheckToken("Bearer " + token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenCheck>() {
            @Override
            public final void onResponse(Call<TokenCheck> call, Response<TokenCheck> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Token check success");
                    ServerRequester.loginResult = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Token check fail! " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public final void onFailure(Call<TokenCheck> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Token check response error! " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        return loginResult;
        }
}
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что значение loginResult всегда == false, хоть и метод onResponse выполняется, судя по LogCat. Как я понял, проблема в том, что метод асинхронный. Из чего вытекает вопрос: 
**Как мне вытащить данные из response, ну или хотя бы получить StatusCode?**
Был вариант выполнить запрос *синхронно*, но андроид бросает ошибку, если сеть крутится в основном потоке *(и не зря)*. Как я понял, нужно поднять отдельный поток. Но то, что я нашёл - создавать отдельный класс и наследоваться от AsyncTask выглядит слишком сложно. Может, есть красивый способ выполнить часть метода (или весь метод) в отдельном потоке и вернуть при этом значение, при этом не создавая новых классов?

Comment: Все верно понимаете, `onResponse()` будет вызван в неопределенный момент в будущем, а его результат вам нужен уже сейчас. Как вам уже ответили -- либо колбэки, либо синхронизация (ждать результат). Первые проще, хоть и не так элегантны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ход рассуждений - абсолютно верный. проблема в том, что потом асинхронный.
AsyncTask - неплохой выход, если бы он не устарел. так что этот вариант отпадает.
можете посмотреть в сторону RxJava и в целом реактивного программирования, но боюсь это отобьет у вас желание разбираться в программирование))

Вариант №1
создавать Callback'и. т.е. весь ваш call.enqueue сделать как отдельный метод и в качестве аргумента передавать ему то, что должно сделать там, где он вызывается.
подход старый, в инете куча инфы по нему, но и он не идеальный.

Вариант №2
Пересесть на Kotlin и познакомится с Коррутинами и LiveData.
Вы указали метку Android, значит рано или поздно вам придется пересесть на Котлин. А вы уже столкнулись с проблемой, которая в Java решается сложно, а в Kotlin'е просто.

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать работать с Callback. Спасибо